# How to search date in a dynamic query using IQueryable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I need to search in sql server database table. I am using `IQueryable` to build a dynamic query like below

```cs
var searchTerm = "12/04";      
var samuraisQueryable = _context.Samurais.Include(x => x.Quotes).AsQueryable();
samuraisQueryable = samuraisQueryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                                    x.CreatedDate.HasValue && x.CreatedDate.Value.ToString()
                                                        .Contains(searchTerm)

var results = samuraisQueryable.ToList();
```

The above query is just an example, actual query in my code is different and more complicated.

Samurai.cs looks like

```cs
public class Samurai
{

    public Samurai()
    {
        Quotes = new List<Quote>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

The data in the table looks like

[image]

I don't see any results becasue the translated SQL from the above query converts the date in a different format (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [s].[CreatedDate])). I tried to specify the date format in the above query but then I get an error that `The LINQ expression cannot be translated`.

```cs
samuraisQueryable = samuraisQueryable.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                                         x.CreatedDate.HasValue && x.CreatedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                                            .Contains(searchTerm)
```

Comment: Remove the question mark from the DateTime object. c# doesn't support nulls for a DateTime.

Comment: Queryable will be evaluated on the server-side so you cannot do `ToString().Contains(...)`. Either you must do `ToList()` first and evaluate that on the client-side, or you must change the expression to not use `Contains()` such as ` x.CreatedDate.Value == yourDateTimeObjectHere`. So you might have to use `DateTime.TryParse` first to see if it is even a valid date.

Comment: @Fred I agree with you but the problem is users will search partially on dates like '12/04' instead of '12/04/2021' (which I can parse and do an equal check) and they will expect a filter on that.

Answer (score 1):

If (comments) users will want to search partially on dates, then honestly: the best thing to do is for *your code* to inspect their input, and parse that into a range query. So; if you see `"12/04"`, you might parse that into a day (in the current year, applying your choice of dd/mm vs mm/dd), and then do a range query on >= that day and < the next day. Similarly, if you see `"2021"`, *your code* should do the same, but as a range query. Trying to do a naïve partial match is not only computationally expensive (and hard to write as a query): it also isn't very useful to the user. Searching just on `"2"` for example - just isn't meaningful as a "contains" query.

Then what you have is:

```cs
(var startInc, var endExc) = ParseRange(searchTerm);
samuraisQueryable = samuraisQueryable.Where(
    x => x.CreatedDate >= startInc && x.CreationDate < endExc);
```